# DB comparison for non-techy PM

Tags: software-development

I am non-techy PM, but I would like to clarify and verify (or just to understand what is going on :) my developer's choice of database with the power of this community.

How should I verify my developers' choice?

Comment: This is a question for software developers, not project managers. But even developers would not be able to give you a solid answer based on that little facts.

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer for the reasons behind the choice? While you might not be able to validate their choice technically you can gain confidence from ensuring the decision making process was done appropriately.

Comment: Systems performance comparisons are off-topic. However, if you can edit the question to be more about how a PM or project management framework can validate this *type* of decision, then it becomes a process question that could be reopened by the community.

Comment: Do you have requirements? Does the choice align with the requirements? Is there evidence?

Comment: I got the inputs from the devs, that NoSQL (current) DB is a bad choice for us, so we should move to something like PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

You're not qualified to second guess your developers. And this is too complex a question to ask on the internet.

I'm sure this is a thing that impact your work, but why do you feel you need to come to some decision on technology. Do you have a very junior team?

Either

1) Trust your people.

2) Hire some better, more senior, more expensive people who you can trust (this can take a long time).

3) Hire a good consultancy company for a second opinion (but... It may annoy your developers and I have no advice on how to tell the good from the bad)